# Why is the edit summary by default the same as the previous edit summary when improving a suggested edit?

Tags: discussion, review, edits, suggested-edits, edit-summary

When a user chooses "Improve" in the Suggested Edits review queue and submit their own edit to improve the suggested one, the edit summary is automatically the same as the edit summary for the suggested edit unless the user who improves it explicitly writes another edit summary. I don't really understand the reason for this. In many cases, what the second edit does isn't the same thing as what the suggested edit does. Here are some examples:

- [Here](https://superuser.com/posts/1249053/revisions) I edited to change a link to an image on a post by a new user who doesn't have enough reputation to post images, so my edit summary was "changed link to image". But then a user who reviewed my suggested edit chose Improve to remove the word "option" which was repeated twice. The edit summary for that edit also became "changed link to image", even though that edit had nothing to do with changing a link to an image.
- [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19609171/revisions) a user edited to correct grammar mistakes but didn't remove noise like "I hope this helps" and "cheers". So I improved the edit to remove that noise, and the edit summary of my edit became "Grammar corrections" even though my edit had nothing to do with grammar.
- [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45918438/revisions) a user edited to indent code that wasn't properly indented, but didn't change the links to images. So I improved the edit to change the links to images, but the edit summary for my edit became "change code style" even though my edit had nothing to do with the code.

There are a lot of other examples where this doesn't make sense, I won't list them all here. There are also cases like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46036168/revisions) where the edit summary does make sense for the second edit, but that's just a coincidence.

I don't understand why the edit summary for the second edit is by default the same as the edit summary for the suggested edit. There is nothing that says that the two edits will fix the same type of issues. Wouldn't it make more sense to either simply have a blank summary like when a user chooses Reject and Edit, or something like "improved user12345's edit"?

Why is the edit summary when improving a suggested edit by default the same as the edit summary for the suggested edit itself? Is there a reason behind this?